# Bootstrap table inside table header alignment issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table inside table header

http://www.bootply.com/H6Glv5owrj

I want to align the last two table headers bottom row with first set of table headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your css as:

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

fixed your [booty](http://www.bootply.com/CPamfOddYS)

Comment: Thanks for your help.Works great.

Comment: @BanTim glad to help you!